# INSERT-SELECT not working with FETCH NEXT [x] ROWS

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have query

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE(NAME,NUM)
SELECT NAME,NUM 
FROM DATA
INNER JOIN T3
ON MYTABLE.NUM = T3.NUM
ORDER BY MYTABLE.NUM
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Running this results in following error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

But when I run above query without the `OFFSET` part it works.

Is `FETCH` incompatible with `INSERT SELECT`?

Comment: [I cannot reproduce this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=541c851fcf27923b965ea13297755d09). But Oracle 11g doesn't have this clause at all, so it will not work either with or without`offset`

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f1d20f635e05f6ec8124960fa1b641b1

Comment: @astentx I have updated the query to help reproduce

Comment: Hmm, your original question and your example are not the same. You need to fully qualify each reference to the column in order to: 1) provide supportability of the query to everyone including future you, when you'll ask yourself where does this column should come from; 2) allow the query to be valid regardless of any new not used columns; 3) avoid unexpected and very hard to find bugs when the column in the filter/join surprisingly comes from another table. If you have two `id` columns in the joined dataset, how Oracle should know which one to use?

Comment: And your example fails regardless of the `offset`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `FETCH` is compatible with `INSERT...SELECT`.  I'm posting this as answer rather than a comment, because it is the answer to the question you posted.

The most common cause of `ORA-00918` with the `FETCH` clause is the caveat that none of the variables in the select list may have the same name.  E.g., this `SELECT` is legal:

```
SELECT object_type, object_name, object_name
FROM   dba_objects
WHERE OBJECT_NAME LIKE 'USER%'
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

.. and this one is not ...

```
SELECT object_type, object_name, object_name
FROM   dba_objects
WHERE OBJECT_NAME LIKE 'USER%'
ORDER BY 1, 2
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Check your query and make sure all the column names / aliases are unique.

#### UPDATE

Reviewing your SQL Fiddle, this is a garden variety ORA-00918.  It has nothing to do with either your `INSERT` or your `FETCH`.  You are joining two tables that have the same columns in them and you are not specifying which you want to select and order by.  Change your statement to this:

```
insert into t2(id, val)
select t.id, t.val
from t
inner join t3
on t.val=t3.val
order by t.id desc
offset 3 rows
fetch first 5 rows only
```